# Django Template is Printing Object Representation instead of Object Value

Tags: python, django, templates, view

`views.py`

```
@login_required 
def ManageDomain(request): 
    AssocNotAuthDomains = Tld.objects.filter(FKtoUser_id=request.user,auth=0)
    AssocAuthDomains = Tld.objects.filter(FKtoUser_id=request.user,auth=1)

    return render(request, 'site/account/template.html', {
         'AssocNotAuthDomains':AssocNotAuthDomains,
         'AssocAuthDomains':AssocAuthDomains
    })
```

`template.html`

```
{% if AssocAuthDomains or AssocNotAuthDomains  %}
<div class="acctDomains">
    <h3 class="Titles"><img src="{% static "img/templated/acct/AuthDomainSm.png" %}" width="22" height="22" alt="Authorized Domain(s)" /> Verified Domains</h3>
    <ul>
    {% for authdomain in AssocAuthDomains %}
        <li>{{ authdomain }}<span><a class="scan" href="/Account/PerformScan/?d={{ authdomain }}">Scan now</span></a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    <h3 class="Titles"><img src="{% static "img/templated/acct/UnAuthDomain.png" %}" width="22" height="22" alt="Unverified Domain(s):" /> Unverified Domains</h3>
    <ul>
    {% for notauthdomain in AssocNotAuthDomains %}
        <li>{{ notauthdomain }}<span><a class="scan" href="Verify Now">Verify now</span></a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div><!--acctDomains-->
```

This prints out:

```
Tld object (1)

Tld object (2)
```

instead of the value e.g. `websiteabc.com`

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implement `__str__` in your model if you want to render a model instance like this

```
class Tld(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        # return something meaningful here like self.some_attribute
```

Or you have to explicitly use an attribute in template like this

```
 {{ authdomain.some_attribute }}
```

Otherwise python does not know how to get something meaningful out of an object to show.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are trying to display the whole object, not the value.

You need to replace

```
{{ notauthdomain }}
```

with

```
{{ notauthdomain.name }}
```

replace 'name' with the field name of your value - websiteabc.com